# Position fixed not working on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm on bootstrap 3, trying to position the "message us" plugin from Facebook at the bottom right of the page:

```
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" messenger_app_id="" page_id="" color="blue" size="xlarge">
</div>

footer .fb-messengermessageus {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I't working fine on desktop (ok even if a resize to the minimum width of the window on Chrome), but the button it's not correctly displayed on mobile, in particular it starts from left and it's hidden for half of its size. How can I fix this?

For completeness: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/message-us

Comment: I guess should be related with the resolution of device. Did you play with media settings? Could you define a proper value for meta viewport? You could define differents values for column using bootstrap as well. Kind of col-xs-4 and so on...

Comment: Hi EliasMP, could you provide an example? I'm relatively new to this field. Should I insert the div with the button inside another "column div"?

Comment: Hi @Jumpa, I am supossing you are coding a standard web and you are having issues when you want to watch it by mobile, isn´t?

Answer (score 1):

First at all, you should define a meta tag for setting resolution fixed by device.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

After, you can define a responsive website using bootstrap framework. 
You must to wrapp all elements in a container.

Then you will define each row in yor web by row ´s class.

Finally, bootstrap define the page in a grid system which mean it divide the page in 12 column. 
You can set how many columns you want to use per element.

For example: col-xs-12 means, this element fill 12 columns (all of them) when the resolution size is xs (extra small).

You can check this url for knowing something more: [Grid´s Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Guessing you problem could be this, the next example will give you the proper approach... Hoping it helps... Any doubt, please, let me know... :)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="fb-messengermessageus col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" messenger_app_id="" page_id="" color="blue" size="xlarge">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I know Bootstrap grid system, I thought that a absolute positioned element could be outside a column/row system. If you look at my site http://giampa.altervista.org/paradise at the bottom I've a similar "go to top" button that works correctly on mobile as well.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am not getting your point. I check your page, you mean the scroll button to the top, it must to be fixed for being watched even when it scrolls...

Comment: I meant that the button "scroll to top" is working fine and is the same as the Facebook button, why the second has issues?

Comment: Turns out that FB add its own CSS at runtime (in particular width 100% when on mobile), so I ended wiring up my custom button from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, I was working. I thought to check your problem after. My english is not good enough... Did you fix it? As far as I can check, you fb´s div is bigger than the smaller resolution, adding width plus position (right displacement). You can play with media queries for changing right displacement and font-size, or try to do this div responsive (default media-queries by bootstrap) using container, row, col, and so on classes. Please, let me know if you didn´t get the solution. I think I could check the problem this weekend...